# VIM: delete until not found with f command

Tags: vim

For example I have the following text:

```
black brown cat bla bla_____
black brown cat bla bla__
black brown cat bla bla_______
black brown cat bla bla___
black brown cat bla bla_____
black brown cat bla bla
```

Each line has various length of underscores(can be any other char)
I want ot delete the underscores from the end of lines using `f` command, delete with `x` until the pattern not found and go to the next line.

The expected result is the lines without the underscored symbol:

```
black brown cat bla bla
black brown cat bla bla
black brown cat bla bla
black brown cat bla bla
black brown cat bla bla
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: pls add the expected output... what if the line is `a_b__c___d_____`? what text do you want to have

Answer (score 3):

the easiest would be:

```
%s/_*$//
```

`f/F` is handy but not for this use case, it leads you to the next `x` char in the line, but doesn't check if there are continuous `x` or if the char next to `x` is `[^x]`.

Only speaking to your example, if you must use `f/F` kind of command, you can do `$vTax`, here I used hardcoded `a`, because you have always `a_____$` but I think your real text won't be like it.

Answer (score 2):

#### With a macro recording…

First, record your macro:

```
qq
f_
D
q
```

Then, play it back on lines in `[range]`:

```
:[range]norm @q
```

Alternatively:

```
:[range]norm f_D
```

#### With a substitution…

```
:[range]s/_\+$
```

Comment: The macro and the `:s` are doing different things. well it depends how do you understand OP's question. E.g. `a__b__c____` should be turned into `a__b__c` or `abc` or `a`

Comment: Both commands do exactly the same thing on the provided sample. If he/she has more complicated requirements he/she should add them to his/her question.